# basex standalone not running 18.04

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, xml

I would like to use basex to perform xquery operations on xml files, as it appears to be more "transparent" than "query string" based filtering.

I installed basex (using APT) on a PC running Ubuntu 18.04.

I then started running through the examples provided in [the manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/basex.1.html)

Well,  `sudo apt-get install basex`  didn't install everything needed (`tagsoup.jar`, `xml-resolver.jar`, and `jing.jar`).

I seem to have found those missing files by installing libs for tagsoup and jing... at least the warning messages stopped.

But basex does not run in standalone mode, as follows:

```
$ basex
BaseX 8.5.1 [Standalone]
Try 'help' to get more information.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.limit(I)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
    at jline.internal.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:104)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.setInput(ConsoleReader.java:330)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:248)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:236)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:224)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.basex.util.ConsoleReader$JLineConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:152)
    at org.basex.util.ConsoleReader.get(ConsoleReader.java:61)
    at org.basex.BaseX.console(BaseX.java:180)
    at org.basex.BaseX.<init>(BaseX.java:166)
```

Any guidance?

Answer (score 1):

I have this running on 18.04 and had the same errors for the 3 missing jar files.
 I installed each of the following `.jar` files manually and everything is working well.

```
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
tagsoup-1.2.1.jar
jing.jar (11/11/09)
```

Comment: what were the commands in apt?  In particular for jing.jar?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause comes from the fact that jline was compiled against jdk9. Detailled explanations are available on this [mongo db ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2559).

So running basex with jdk 9 should be OK.

Comment: but how is jing installed for newer Java's?