# How to install jing-trang with apt?

Tags: apt, package-management, java, libraries, xml

How is `jing-trang` installed with `apt`?  Having already [installed](https://askubuntu.com/q/1070990/847449):

```
libtagsoup-java     
libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java
```

with apt, it's just this one [package](https://github.com/relaxng/jing-trang) which is proving elusive.  So far:

```
xhtml-relaxng is already the newest version (20220510-2).
```

so it must be something else which pulls in that library.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:    23.04
Codename:   lunar
```

Answer (score 0):

leaving this here for the next poor soul trying to install this package:

```
sudo apt install jing
```

works for me.  it seems to pull in about ten other packages for whatever reason, but solves the problem.